# Text Field для перехода по URL

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Привет, в моем iOS приложении есть Text Field, нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе в нем URL-ссылки открывался сафари и выполнялся переход по ссылке. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Ruslan_T](/users/20566/ruslan_t)](/users/20566/ruslan_t), вам следует учить мат часть.

По окончании ввода текста вызывается метод делегата. Как вам было сказано, вызываете метод открытия урла. Что тут неясно то? Например:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{ 
    [self openMyUrl:textField.text];
}

- (void)openMyUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В целом все просто - достаточно повесить на окончание редактирования (насколько помню там даже два способа сделать это - через делегат поля и через центр нотификации)метод в котором будет открываться ссылка, перегнать текст в урл легко - у NSURL есть соотвествующий метод, открыть потом этот урл тоже - у UIApplication есть метод openURL, ну и по хорошему надо бы проверить валидный ли урл (у того же UIApplication  есть canOpenURL или что-то в этом роде). В чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я начинающий, и понял только половину того, что вы написали. Я могу сделать кнопку, при нажатии на которую происходит переход по ссылке, так что про UIApplication я понял, а вот первая половина того, что вы написали, мне непонятна.

Comment: Я написал практически весь алгоритм, дальше надо писать конкретный код, чего делать у меня нет ни временини желания. Если хотите по нажатию на кнопку то все еще проще - не надо никаких делегатов, просто при нажатии на кнопку берете текст из поля и преобразуете его в NSURL (у него есть метод URLWithString), далее все так же. В целом же если вам  не понятна половина того что я написал значит вы рано начали писать приложение, надо было сначала почитать что-нибудь про OBj-C и iOS

Comment: @aknew, уже стесняюсь спросить у "интересующегося", знает ли, как ВЗЯТЬ тот самый текст из поля))

Comment: @AlessandroDP , я по этому почти перестал отвечать на вопросы - мало того что отдельные вопросы типа "как передать данные в другой контроллер" встречаются чуть ли не раз в два месяца, так еще и добрая половина выглядит как пункт ТЗ - человек даже не пишет что он пробовал - просто мне надо то-то и то-то, да еще обязательно чтоб рабочий код был.

Comment: @aknew, я про это уже писал, и про дизлайки, чтоб не снимали рейт с меня - сказали есть кнопка тревога, если вопрос совсем уж - но с ее помощью то тоже рейт мне минусуется... непонятки. Учите матчасть, товарищи!!!